# Google dual x-axis charts with value 0

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts and I have a bar chart with dual x-axis. I have the following data:
`[name, person1Score, person2Score]` as you can see below some of these values are 0. That is because some people haven't done the test yet (and never will), so they have no score.

```
[ 'ORG', 30, 40 ],
[ 'OTH', 15, 20 ],
[ 'PAX', 20, 0],
[ 'FM', 35, 30 ],
[ 'CRW', 25, 0],
[ 'TRX', 0, 30 ],
[ 'WEA', 0, 20 ]
```

When I create my chart it looks like this. As you can see for CRW and TRX the lines are not centered. There is an empty space where the bar with value 0 should be.

[image]

Is is possible to center the bar so it aligns with the name on the left axis, when the value is 0?

https://jsfiddle.net/3hycxqmo/

Comment: there are no options you can set -- you could move the bar manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event, but the chart will move it back on any interactivity, such as "hover" -- so not much you can do unless you want to disable interactivity on the chart...

Comment: @WhiteHat moving it manually seems to much work for the little visual upgrade it gets. Hope I won't notice it anymore after a while